# ODE problem using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to use DSolve (or NDSolve) to verify that the solution to the ODE problem

```
-4(v''[t]+(2/t)v'[t])-2*v[t]*Log[v[t]]-(3+(3/2)Log[4 Pi])*v[t]==0,
```

for $t\geq 0$ with conditions $\lim_{t\to \infty}v(t)=0$ and $v'(0)=0$ is given by the Gaussian

```
v[t]=(4 Pi)^(-3/4)*Exp[-t^2/8].
```

I am able to verify this by hand, but am having trouble using Mathematica to verify it. I would like to use Mathematica to solve this (simple) differential equation, so that I can later on modify some terms in the ODE to see how the solution changes.

Perhaps I am making a foolish mistake. I have also tried using NDSolve, but did not obtain the correct solution. I would appreciate any tips. Below you can find my code as well as the picture of the error messages. Thanks for your help.

[Picture of updated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMiOF.png)

```
sol=DSolve[{-4(v''[t]+(2/t)v'[t])-2*v[t]*Log[v[t]]
    -(3+(3/2)Log[4 Pi])*v[t]==0,v[Infinity]==0,v'[0]==0},v[t],t]
Plot[Evaluate[v[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Edit:** Changed `r` to `t` to correct a typo. The output is still the same as before.

Comment: If you drop the boundary conditions, `DSolve` cannot solve for the general solution, which means there's little hope to get `DSolve` to do it on its own. The particular solution for the BVP might be a special case that someone was able to derive. `NDSolve` doesn't deal with infinity, so you have problems at both boundary conditions.  You could use engineer's approximations, e.g. `10^-8` for `0`, and `10` or `100` or whatever for infinity (depends on scale). Still seems difficult. Maybe do shooting manually.

Answer (score 1):

As MichaelE2 noted, `DSolve` seems unable to solve this ODE system, even when boundary conditions are omitted.  I also tried the transformation,

```
eq = -4 (v''[t] + (2/t) v'[t]) - 2*v[t]*Log[v[t]] - (3 + (3/2) Log[4 Pi])*v[t] == 0;
eq /. v -> Function[{t}, Exp[w[t]]];
Simplify[0 == -2 Exp[-w[t]] First@%, w[t] \[Element] Reals]
(* 6 + 3 Log[4 Pi] + 4 w[t] + (16 w'[t])/t + 8 w'[t]^2 + 8 w''[t] == 0 *)
```

but `DSolve[%, w[t], t, Assumptions -> t > 0]` still returned unevaluated.

It is, however, possible to compare the desired solution,

```
s = (4 Pi)^(-3/4)*Exp[-t^2/8]
```

with a numerical solution of the ODE.

```
tmin = 10^-7; 
NDSolveValue[{eq, v[tmin] == .1498278, v'[tmin] == 0}, v[t], {t, tmin, 10}];
LogPlot[{%, s}, {t, tmin, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, v}, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

where the numerical solution agrees well with `s` over four orders of magnitude before diverging, which is inevitable for such problems.  The initial condition, `v[tmin] == .1498278` was developed by trial and error in just a few minutes.  Automating the process is, of course, possible.

Incidentally, Mathematica also can be used to validate `s` directly by,

```
Simplify[eq /. v -> Function[{t}, Evaluate@s], t > 0]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Your" solution doesn't solve the ode:

```
ode=-4 (v''[t] + (2/r) v'[t]) -2*v[t]*Log[v[t]] - (3 + (3/2) Log[4 Pi])*v[t] == 0 

ode/.v -> Function[t, (4 Pi)^(-3/4)*Exp[-t^2/8]] // Simplify
(*(E^(-(t^2/8)) (-8 t + r (8 + t^2) + 8 r Log[E^(-(t^2/8))]))/r == 0*)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I was assuming that `r=t`, in which case my solution does solve the ODE. I have now adjusted the ODE accordingly (it was a typo). However, I am still getting similar error messages (see new picture). Do you have any suggestions for how to find the solution using DSolve or NDSolve?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you give solves the ODE under very specific condition, which is at one point only, given by `r=t`

```
ode=-4(v''[t]+(2/r)v'[t])-2*v[t]*Log[v[t]]-(3+(3/2)Log[4 Pi])*v[t]==0;
sol=v->Function[{t},(4 Pi)^(-3/4)*Exp[-t^2/8]];
Assuming[{t>0,t==r},Simplify[ode/.sol]]

(*True*)
```

> I am able to verify this by hand

The solution you give satisfies the boundary conditions. But a solution to the ODE have to also satisfy the ODE itself as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I was indeed assuming that `r=t` and have now adjusted the ODE accordingly (it was a typo). However, I am still getting similar error messages (see new picture). Do you have any suggestions for how to find the solution using DSolve or NDSolve?